# Sublime auto compile main.less when using partials

Tags: css, less

I have just started to use *less* with Sublime, I have setup *less2css* to autocompile `.less` files when they are saved and to ignore partials.

I have a main.less which imports other `.less` files e.g. `_global.less` but this means every time I make a change to global I have to save it then go back into `main.less` to compile it.

Is there any way to get `main.less` to autocompile when any partial is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out, for anyone having the same issue in the future the solution I have found is to edit "main_file" in less2css settings so for my example above I have put:

```
"main_file": "main.less",
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start using npm, yarn or gulp if you prefer that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less